# How can I schedule a daily backup with SQL Server Express?

Tags: backup, sql-server-express, scheduled-tasks

I'm running a small web application with SQL server express (2005) as backend. I can create a backup with a SQL script, however, I'd like to schedule this on a  daily basis. As extra option (should-have) I'd like to keep only the last X backups (for space-saving reasons obviously) Any pointers?

[edit] SQL server agent is unavailable in SQL server express...

Comment: You can simply do it using SQLBackupAndFTP https://sqlbackupandftp.com/

Comment: You may check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29893738/1101112. It's batch file to make a sql server express database backup and keep the last 10 backups (auto remove old). It should be use with windows scheduler to make it automatic perform periodically.

Answer (score 55):

### Eduardo Molteni had a great answer:

- [SQL Server Automated Backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493886/sql-server-automated-backups/493952#493952)

> Using Windows Scheduled Tasks:
>
> **In the batch file**

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S 
(local)\SQLExpress -i D:\dbbackups\SQLExpressBackups.sql
```

> **In SQLExpressBackups.sql**

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDataBase1 TO  DISK = N'D:\DBbackups\MyDataBase1.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'MyDataBase1 Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

BACKUP DATABASE MyDataBase2 TO  DISK = N'D:\DBbackups\MyDataBase2.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'MyDataBase2 Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

GO
```

Comment: anyway to append a timestamp to the created backup file so that it does not write to existing file?

Comment: Great! Also, I had to follow this to get correct permissions to create the backup file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960257/cannot-open-backup-device-operating-system-error-5

Comment: Damien > if you want to have backups for more days, replace INIT param with NOINIT. INIT means that backup file is always rewritten from scratch. You should use the way with a timestamp as you said or use NOINIT params which append backup to existig file. It's good practice to use something like RETAINDAYS param otherwise backup file will growth forever. In case of timestamp you would have to solve it by your self. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx for more informations

Comment: Remember to set backup location within the SQL installation folders. I was getting: "SQL Server Operating system error 5: 5(Access is denied.)” because I set my backup to go outside the "official" SQL server installation folder (SQL Server database engine service account must have permissions to read/write in the new folder). Alternatively, look through [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286765/sql-server-operating-system-error-5-5access-is-denied)

Comment: For SQL Server 2014 Express, SqlCmd.exe is now located at: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE"

Answer (score 54):

You cannot use the SQL Server agent in SQL Server Express.
The way I have done it before is to create a SQL Script, and then run it as a scheduled task each day, you could have multiple scheduled tasks to fit in with your backup schedule/retention. The command I use in the scheduled task is:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -i"c:\path\to\sqlbackupScript.sql"

Comment: Lovely, nice and slick. Cheers!

Comment: only works if you have that kind of access to the server

Comment: Microsoft has supplied a nice script and detailed instructions for accomplishing this task.  The main thing it lacks is cleanup of old backup files.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698

Answer (score 7):

Just use [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698) script to dynamically backup all databases on the server. Then create batch file according to the article. It is usefull to create two batch files, one for full backup a and one for diff backup. Then Create two tasks in Task Scheduler, one for full and one for diff.

```
-- // Copyright © Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.
-- // This code released under the terms of the
-- // Microsoft Public License (MS-PL, http://opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html.)
USE [master] 
GO 
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_BackupDatabases] ******/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

-- ============================================= 
-- Author: Microsoft 
-- Create date: 2010-02-06
-- Description: Backup Databases for SQLExpress
-- Parameter1: databaseName 
-- Parameter2: backupType F=full, D=differential, L=log
-- Parameter3: backup file location
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BackupDatabases]  
            @databaseName sysname = null,
            @backupType CHAR(1),
            @backupLocation nvarchar(200) 
AS 

       SET NOCOUNT ON; 

            DECLARE @DBs TABLE
            (
                  ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                  DBNAME nvarchar(500)
            )

             -- Pick out only databases which are online in case ALL databases are chosen to be backed up
             -- If specific database is chosen to be backed up only pick that out from @DBs
            INSERT INTO @DBs (DBNAME)
            SELECT Name FROM master.sys.databases
            where state=0
            AND name=@DatabaseName
            OR @DatabaseName IS NULL
            ORDER BY Name

            -- Filter out databases which do not need to backed up
            IF @backupType='F'
                  BEGIN
                  DELETE @DBs where DBNAME IN ('tempdb','Northwind','pubs','AdventureWorks')
                  END
            ELSE IF @backupType='D'
                  BEGIN
                  DELETE @DBs where DBNAME IN ('tempdb','Northwind','pubs','master','AdventureWorks')
                  END
            ELSE IF @backupType='L'
                  BEGIN
                  DELETE @DBs where DBNAME IN ('tempdb','Northwind','pubs','master','AdventureWorks')
                  END
            ELSE
                  BEGIN
                  RETURN
                  END

            -- Declare variables
            DECLARE @BackupName varchar(100)
            DECLARE @BackupFile varchar(100)
            DECLARE @DBNAME varchar(300)
            DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000) 
        DECLARE @dateTime NVARCHAR(20)
            DECLARE @Loop int                  

            -- Loop through the databases one by one
            SELECT @Loop = min(ID) FROM @DBs

      WHILE @Loop IS NOT NULL
      BEGIN

-- Database Names have to be in [dbname] format since some have - or _ in their name
      SET @DBNAME = '['+(SELECT DBNAME FROM @DBs WHERE ID = @Loop)+']'

-- Set the current date and time n yyyyhhmmss format
      SET @dateTime = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),101),'/','') + '_' +  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),108),':','')  

-- Create backup filename in path\filename.extension format for full,diff and log backups
      IF @backupType = 'F'
            SET @BackupFile = @backupLocation+REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME, '[',''),']','')+ '_FULL_'+ @dateTime+ '.BAK'
      ELSE IF @backupType = 'D'
            SET @BackupFile = @backupLocation+REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME, '[',''),']','')+ '_DIFF_'+ @dateTime+ '.BAK'
      ELSE IF @backupType = 'L'
            SET @BackupFile = @backupLocation+REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME, '[',''),']','')+ '_LOG_'+ @dateTime+ '.TRN'

-- Provide the backup a name for storing in the media
      IF @backupType = 'F'
            SET @BackupName = REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME,'[',''),']','') +' full backup for '+ @dateTime
      IF @backupType = 'D'
            SET @BackupName = REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME,'[',''),']','') +' differential backup for '+ @dateTime
      IF @backupType = 'L'
            SET @BackupName = REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME,'[',''),']','') +' log backup for '+ @dateTime

-- Generate the dynamic SQL command to be executed

       IF @backupType = 'F' 
                  BEGIN
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' +@DBNAME+  ' TO DISK = '''+@BackupFile+ ''' WITH INIT, NAME= ''' +@BackupName+''', NOSKIP, NOFORMAT'
                  END
       IF @backupType = 'D'
                  BEGIN
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' +@DBNAME+  ' TO DISK = '''+@BackupFile+ ''' WITH DIFFERENTIAL, INIT, NAME= ''' +@BackupName+''', NOSKIP, NOFORMAT'        
                  END
       IF @backupType = 'L' 
                  BEGIN
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP LOG ' +@DBNAME+  ' TO DISK = '''+@BackupFile+ ''' WITH INIT, NAME= ''' +@BackupName+''', NOSKIP, NOFORMAT'        
                  END

-- Execute the generated SQL command
       EXEC(@sqlCommand)

-- Goto the next database
SELECT @Loop = min(ID) FROM @DBs where ID>@Loop

END
```

And batch file can look like this:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\myDB -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='c:\Dropbox\backup\DB\', @backupType='F'"  >> c:\Dropbox\backup\DB\full.log 2>&1
```

and

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\myDB -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='c:\Dropbox\backup\DB\', @backupType='D'"  >> c:\Dropbox\backup\DB\diff.log 2>&1
```

The advantage of this method is that you don't need to change anything if you add new database or delete a database, you don't even need to list the databases in the script. Answer from JohnB is better/simpler for server with one database, this approach is more suitable for multi database servers.

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks for this! +1

Answer (score 4):

The folks at MSSQLTips have some very helpful articles, the one most relevant for this is "[Automating SQL Server 2005 Express Backups and Deletion of Older Backup Files](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1486)"

The basic approach is to set up two tasks using the Windows Task Scheduler. One task runs a TSQL script that generates separate backup files for all MSSQL databases (except TEMPDB) with the database name and a date/time stamp in the file name into a specified directory. The second task runs a VBScript script that goes through that directory and deletes all files with a .BAK extension that are more than 3 days old.

Both scripts **require** minor editing for your environment (paths, how long to keep those database dumps) but are very close to drop-in-and-run.

Note that there are possible security implications if you're sloppy with these or with directory permissions, since they are plain text files that will need to run with some level of privilege. Don't be sloppy.

Comment: Also worth noting - if you're using DFS to automate pushing of backup files to other systems, keep in mind that .bak is normally an excluded extension - either change it or change the filtering.

Answer (score 3):

We have used the combination of:

1. [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) for scheduling/maintenance
2. [ExpressMaint](http://www.codeplex.com/ExpressMaint) for backup

Both of these are free. The process is to script ExpressMaint to take a backup as a Cobian "before Backup" event. I usually let this overwrite the previous backup file. Cobian then takes a zip/7zip out of this and archives these to the backup folder. In Cobian you can specify the number of full copies to keep, make multiple backup cycles etc.

ExpressMaint command syntax example:

```
expressmaint -S HOST\SQLEXPRESS -D ALL_USER -T DB -R logpath -RU WEEKS -RV 1 -B backuppath -BU HOURS -BV 3
```

Comment: cobian is dead ;(

Comment: @PiotrKula Cobian Backup is still freeware and available from this site https://www.cobiansoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a backup device in server object, let us say

> BDTEST

and then create a batch file contain following command

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.1.25 -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE dbtest TO BDTEST"
```

let us say with name

> backup.bat

then you can call

> backup.bat

in task scheduler according to your convenience