# SQL Access denied error for a folder with 'Share with Nobody' property

Tags: c++, sql-server

I need to create a backup of my database and then restore the same on my PC. I am copying my backup file to another folder( Eg: 'Example' ) and setting the property as **'Share with Nobody'** to the folder( Right click on the 'Example' folder->Share with->Nobody ). If I try to perform a restore operation after this, I am getting below Access denied error.

> SQL Error : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot
>   open backup device 'C:\Temp\Example\Example.bak'. Operating system
>   error 5(Access is denied.).

This scenario is reproduced when we ran the query

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Temp\Example\Example.bak'
```

Comment: Probably MS SQL server has no access to the directory?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286765/sql-server-operating-system-error-5-5access-is-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Sql Server instance needs permissions to read the backup file. Make sure the service account that's running Sql Server has rights to access the file share.

Comment: By doing this, the folder will lose the permissions due to which the access is denied to the SQL server.