# SQL Server - error 5 access denied

Tags: sql-server

I try to attach a database and get an "error 5 access denied" error. I changed the permisions on the folder for the user "NT Service\MSSQL$MS64BITSQLSERVER" and gave full access but the error is still there.

The SQL Server service logs on as "NT Service\MSSQL$MS64BITSQLSERVER"

I'm sure that is an problem with the access rights. Any further suggestions?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286765/sql-server-operating-system-error-5-5access-is-denied)

Comment: Did you run SSMS as Administrator?

Comment: Add the Administrators Group to the file security permissions with full control for the Data file and the Log File.

Comment: No. But the user which starts the SSMS is an adminstrator as well.

Comment: @gofr1 Administrators group is already added with full access. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The user which connects to database via windows authentication is already an Admin. But I must gave the user additional explicit full access on the folder which contains the files (properties/security). After that the error 5 file access disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Share the SQL's DATA folder,  give full access.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).