# Attach sql server 2012 error, Unable to open the physical file

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I got message box

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Project Basdat\DAYCARE.mdf".
>   Operating system error 5: "5(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

when trying to attach database file that I made from another pc.

I use Windows 10.

Help :(

Comment: Error 5 is access denied, either put the database files in the SQL server data folder that was defined during setup or add permissions on that new folder to allow the service account access to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286765/sql-server-operating-system-error-5-5access-is-denied)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link I posted previously is broken so I removed it. If you run SQL Server Management Studio as administrator it should work just fine.

Comment: From the link is the answer: "...running the Management Studio Instance as an administrator"

Comment: Thanks to @Reid for the quick help as opposed to the condescending answer from @Petaflop!

Comment: @hurleystylee updated the answer, thanks for your straightforward comment

Comment: @Petaflop don't you agree?  Could have done without the "If you google for 2 minutes" part.  People come here as part of their first 2 minutes of googling.

Comment: @hurleystylee I think that pointing out these things is sometimes part of learning, but that would be an extended discussion this place is not for.

Comment: @Petaflop -1 for the 2 minutes comment.  Unnecessary.

Comment: Good answer, the first link I clicked in Google;), less than 10 sec as opposed to 2 min:)

Answer (score 0):

This is permission issue on folder.

GO to the folder where you have stored mdf file.
 select file-> Right click -> click on .
 give full permissions to file for logged in user Security and (NT Service\MSSQLSERVER).

Comment: This is correct assuming you are using the default built in accounts for SQL server, if you have used a different service account, you need to add folder permissions that reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this issue, I tried

1. Running SQL Management Studio as Administrator
2. Giving full permissions to the file for logged in user

Still the error persisted. 
The reason for this error might be that you copied your program from a source which Windows considers non-trusted.

You can unblock the assembly by clicking **"Unblock"** after you right-click and select properties on the file.