# Scheduling daily task on SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and trying to make schedule to run a page every mid-night but I don't know how to do it. I already tried to do with SQL JOBS but couldn't find JOB folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a full SQL Server product (not Express), just follow the steps from Books Online

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

FYI - The folder "Jobs" is under "SQL Server Agent" in the Object Explorer tree.

If you are asking about Express, then refer to answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487675/how-can-i-schedule-a-daily-backup-with-sql-server-express) or a neat trick [using SQL Server Service Broker](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express)

Comment: The SQL version is Express Edition with Advanced and its 2008 not 2005. Do you think its gonna work on 2008 as well?

Comment: The techniques linked work with 2008 (and R2 for that matter) as well as 2005.  Personally, I prefer the simple scheduling of SQLCMD.exe using Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: I just used Windows Task Scheduler. It works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great to see the problem solved. Welcome to stackoverflow. When you are happy with an answer (you can always wait indefinitely for more suggestions), please tick one off as the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

to schedule PAGE (script) running look in Task Manager