# How to send mail through sql server 2005 express without sql server agent?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hello can any one send me proper solution on it that i want to send mail through sql server 2005 express . i know that through sql server agent but in sql server 2005 express has no sql server agent but there is another way is to send mail by scheduler but i dont know the exact procedure to send mail . send me some solution on it or send me solution how to installed sql server agent in sql server 2005 express??????

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3626056/Database-Mail-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

Answer (score 0):

Visit the following SO thread for details on options for deploying a scheduler for SQL Express

[How can I schedule a daily backup with SQL Server Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487675/how-can-i-schedule-a-daily-backup-with-sql-server-express)