# How to take table backup in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

I have one SQL Server database table. I need to take backup of my table daily based on the date. For that I need to write a script. But I'm new to SQL Server can any one please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this URL 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487675/how-can-i-schedule-a-daily-backup-with-sql-server-express

Comment: That's fine. In my requirement i need to take backup of data based on the date.for example In my table i have last one month details. i need to  taken backup of first 15 days backup and also i need to delete the 15days details in my database

Comment: This everything should perform in automatically

Answer (score 2):

You could copy it with command

```
select * into new_table1 from primarytable
```

This will create a table named `new_table1` with data from `primarytable`.

You must of course backup the whole database.