# cannot find maintenance plans folder under managment in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Unable to find maintenance plans folder under management in **sql server 2012**

But executing this query finds maintenance plans in ssispackagefolder.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.sysssispackagefolders
```

An the result is

```
folder id                               parentfolderid                          folder name
08AA12D5-8F98-4DAB-A4FC-980B150A5DC8    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    Maintenance Plans
```

Comment: Check http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/no-maintenance-plans-folder-in-sql-studio-2008-r2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether your server is **not the Express edition** running following command:

```
select CASE WHEN @@version LIKE '%Express%' THEN 'Express' ELSE 'OK' END
```

Note that even on the SQL Server Express edition the `Maintenance plans` folder is present in `dbo.sysssispackagefolders` table.

On Express edition the Maintenance plans feature is not available because it does not include the SQL server agent. You must use another tool like Windows Taks Scheduler to schedule running backups etc., see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487675/how-can-i-schedule-a-daily-backup-with-sql-server-express).